# Xamarin Forms - Why Is LineBreakMode TailTruncation Causing Word Wrap

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, word-wrap, truncation

In a Xamarin Forms project (C# code, not XAML), I have a some nested horizontal stacklayouts that look like this:

[image]

Notice there's a "Declined:" Label, then a quantity Label (4), and then a reason code Label ("Can't Find"). I have set the reason code Label to a LineBreakMode of `LineBreakMode.TailTruncation`. I would expect that when the label gets too long to fit on the line, it would truncate it with ellipses. It does. **However**, it doesn't do it gracefully - it causes things to be squished and to word wrap, like this:

[image]

I have set the "Declined:" Label to `LineBreakMode.NoWrap`, and you'll notice the last "d" in "Declined" is cut off". I haven't set any LineBreakMode on the "Ordered" and "Picked" Labels, and you'll notice those word wrap. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe provide your StackLayout with a fixed Width value?

Comment: @Jerrak0s - doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @jbyrd Did you find a solution for this? I'm currently struggling with exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Does it look normal again when you rotate the device or if you call `ForceLayout()` on the parent element to all of those nested `StackLayout`s?

I have noticed that sometimes I must do that to force a redraw or layout pass on certain devices (usually is it only needed on one platforms or another as opposed to all platforms).

If that doesn't work, I would suggest using `Grid` if that is possible in your situation. That is what I tend to do when I run into elements sitting on top of each other like this. I am not sure why it happens but `Grid` never fails me. `Grid` seems to be much more strict about spacing and does not let things bleed over like that

Comment: I tried both. I tried ForceLayout() on the container, with no effect. I also tried using a grid - and it actually pushed the buttons right off the screen!

Comment: @jbyrd Haha did you include the buttons in the `Grid`?